# How to switch screens in a rust tui app (termion + tui-rs)

Tags: rust, tui

I have a tui app where a user is presented with some choices through a list. Once they navigate to the choice they want and hit enter I'd like to take them to the "next" screen.

It's more complicated than just clearning existing text and printing new one because I also need to replace keybindings and basically start a new `tui-rs` loop. More below.

Code for Screen 1:

```
pub fn draw_screen() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // Terminal initialization
    let stdout = io::stdout().into_raw_mode()?;
    let stdout = MouseTerminal::from(stdout);
    let stdout = AlternateScreen::from(stdout);
    let backend = TermionBackend::new(stdout);
    let mut terminal = Terminal::new(backend)?;

    let events = Events::new();

    loop {
        terminal.draw(|f| {
            // user shown a list they can navigate through using arrow keys
        });

        match events.next()? {
            Event::Input(input) => match input {
                Key::Char('q') => {
                    break;
                }
                Key::Char('\n') => {
                    // this is where I need to "send" them to a new screen
                }
                Key::Down => {
                    // my_list won't exist on next screen
                    my_list.items.next();
                }
                Key::Up => {
                    my_list.items.previous();
                }
                _ => {}
            },
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

As can be seen the keybindings at the bottom are specific to this screen. Eg on the next screen there's not going to be a `my_list` and instead there might be a `my_another_list` or `my_box` or nothing at all.

So if all I did was clear the text, I'd still be left inside the same loop with the same keybindings - doesn't work.

What's the right way to initiate a new loop with fresh keybindings?

Comment: I would do this as a state machine, where each screen has it's own state (and possibly sub-states). example: https://github.com/peterjoel/inspector/blob/master/cli/src/console.rs#L22

Comment: @PeterHall - hey, thanks for commenting, that turned out to be the right abstraction! I managed to build a state machine which swaps out both what's on the screen and the keybindings. Here's the code -> https://gist.github.com/ilmoi/38c4d7d04a265f6a4c829b1648fdde2d Feel free to post the answer I'll mark it as correct.